# Modifiy class attribute inside Meteor.setInterval function

Tags: javascript, meteor, setinterval

I need to do:

```
TestClass = function(){
   this.left =10
   this.finterval = function(){
       console.log("this.finterval:"+JSON.stringify(intervalId))
       this.left =  this.left -1
       Meteor.clearInterval(intervalId)
   }
   var intervalId = Meteor.setInterval(this.finterval,1000)
   console.log("this.intervalId:" + this.intervalId)
}
```

Is there a way to modify this.left inside the interval method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` always refers to the current scope so you need to assign it to another var (ex `self`) if you're nesting functions:

```
TestClass = function(){
   this.left =10
   var self = this;
   this.finterval = function(){
       console.log("this.finterval:"+JSON.stringify(intervalId))
       self.left =  self.left -1
       Meteor.clearInterval(intervalId)
   }
   var intervalId = Meteor.setInterval(this.finterval,1000)
   console.log("this.intervalId:" + this.intervalId)
}
```

Comment: that way we modify self var values. But it also change this values at once?

Comment: I have checked and yes. It does it :)

Comment: Yes, when assigning a functions or an object to a variable a reference is created, not a new copy of the object/function.